# Git, is it possible to preserve changes for future?

Tags: git

I have some code which should be reverted for now but I will need it later. Is it somehow possible to revert but preserve changed classes for future use?

EDIT:
I know, it's possible to move them to separate change list and ignore on commit. But that's not what I need. I actually need to keep both versions of files.

Thank you.

Comment: Both versions can not coexist in a single file system. Both version, however, can be put in separate branches. BTW: the android-studio tag is misused, it has no direct relation with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this is feasible.

1. First revert to the commit you wish to keep
2. Create a branch based on the reverted commit
3. Revert back to the head

Now you have both!

Specifically:

```
git checkout -b 0x1234 // get the old code and create a new branch based on it
git checkout master head // head is the tip of your current master
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `git stash`. No, really, I know you already accepted the other answer, but do yourself a favour and try `git help stash`; the two commands you use 99% of the time are `git stash` and `git stash pop`.